# Starcounter - Changing the datatype of a property

Tags: c#, starcounter

How can we safely change the `datatype` of a property of a `Starcounter` database class if the corresponding table has existing data?

Example

existing: `int PostalCode`

desired:  `string PostalCode`

Comment: Can you clarify, which version of Starcounter you are using, since the product is changing all the time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing property of a database class means refactoring database schema, i.e., changing type of the corresponding column. Such changes are not supported seamlessly and no build-in tool is provided by Starcounter. It can be done manually, but it is quite cumbersome.

I see two approaches:

1. Unload the database using [stardump](https://docs.starcounter.io/guides/working-with-starcounter/migrating-from-2.2-to-2.3+#the-stardump-tool) tool and modifying the schema and data using external tool such as SQLite.
2. Through several steps of changing the app schema first move data from `int` column into `string` column and then rename column into the original one.

Remember to always backup your database.

I describe the second approach in more details.

#### Step I: move data from int to string

1. Add new property of `string` type to the database class, e.g., `PostalCodeString`
2. Add and execute application code, which will go through all instances of the class and set `PostalCodeString` to the value converted from original `int` `PostalCode`
3. Stop the application and execute SQL statement to drop the column: `ALTER TABLE TheClassName DROP COLUMN PostalCode`
4. Remove the old property `PostalCode` from the class definition and remove the conversion code.
5. Start the application and test that it works as expected

#### Step II: rename column

1. Add new property with the old column name, i.e., `PostalCode` of type `string`
2. Move data from `PostalCodeString` to `PostalCode` in the similar way as step I, i.e., by application code going through all instances of the class.
3. Drop column `PostalCodeString`

I haven't tested these steps myself, but I expect it to work. The main concern is creating `PostalCode` in step II.

**EDIT:** the drop column SQL statement is only fully supported in latest release candidates since December 18, 2017.

Comment: Thank you k_rus. I have done these steps before, I was just wondering if that is the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

If PostalCode is just a int then this should work.

```
PostalCode.ToString();
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is referring to

Comment: What she wants, I think, is to change a table's column data type from `int` to `string`. She should be clearer, as you stated

Comment: I'd assume there should be a sql version of ToString();

Comment: Well if it's not clear what is being ask - just ask for clarification in comment, why post some wild guesses as answers?